# How to get a Task that uses SynchronizationContext? And how are SynchronizationContext used anyway?

Tags: c#, async-await, synchronizationcontext

I am still learning the whole Task-concept and TPL. From my current understanding, the SynchronizationContext functions (if present) are used by `await` to dispatch the Task "somewhere". On the other hand, the functions in the `Task` class do not use the context, right?

So for example `Task.Run(...)` will always dispatch the action on an worker thread of the thread pool and ignore the `SynchronizationContext.Current` completely. `await Foobar()` would use the context to execute the generated task after the `await`?

If that is true, my question is: How can I obtain a `Task`, that actually runs an action but is dispatched using `SynchronizationContext.Current.Send/Post` ?

And can anyone recommend a good introduction into `SynchronizationContext`, especially when and how they are used by the rest of the framework? The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) seems to be very quiet about the class. The top Google hits ([here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14265/The-NET-Framework-s-New-SynchronizationContext-Cla) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31971/Understanding-SynchronizationContext-Part-I)) seem to be tailored to Windows Forms dispatching only. Stephen Cleary wrote [an article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx) which is nice to learn what contexts already exist and how they work, but I lack understanding of where and when they are actually used.

Answer (score 52):

> How can I obtain a Task, that actually runs an action but is dispatched using 
>   SynchronizationContext.Current.Send/Post?

Use special task scheduler:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(
    () => {}, // this will use current synchronization context
    CancellationToken.None, 
    TaskCreationOptions.None, 
    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

> And can anyone recommend a good introduction into SynchronizationContext

Look at the article [*It's All About the SynchronizationContext*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx) by Stephen Cleary.

Comment: ah, nice. thanks. Is there any difference between `Task.Run` and `Task.Factory.StartNew` ? (I mean.. any other difference than that "`Task.Factory.StartNew` accept some parameter which `Task.Run` does not" ;))

Comment: _Look at this article._ Thank you for the link. I already read that article and linked it in my question - very good for understanding what contexts exist and why they were introduced in the first place. Any other good sources, maybe going into detail about which class uses the contexts when? Or do I approach the TPL wrongly and I should read about "Why I should actually never care about this"? :D.

Comment: There *are* some other [differences between `Task.Run` and `Task.Factory.StartNew`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx): `Task.Run` understands and automatically unwraps `async` delegates, `Task.Run` always uses the thread pool scheduler (while `Task.Factory.StartNew` will use the current task scheduler), and `Task.Run` will pass the `DenyChildAttach` option by default.

Comment: Should there be `TaskCreationOptions.None` instead of `TaskContinuationOptions.None`?

Answer (score 28):

As you're learning this, it's important to point out that `Task` *as used by the TPL* is quite different than `Task` *as used by async/await*, even though they're the same type. For example, TPL commonly uses parent/child tasks, but `async`/`await` does not.

TPL uses task schedulers to execute its tasks. As Dennis pointed out, `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` will give you a task scheduler that uses `Post` on the current `SynchronizationContext` to execute its task.

`async`/`await` usually does not use task schedulers. I have an introductory [`async`/`await` post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) on my blog that includes context information, and I also mention it briefly in my [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx) (it's easy to overlook, though). Essentially, when an `async` method suspends at an `await`, by default it will capture the current `SynchronizationContext` (unless it is `null`, in which case it will capture the current `TaskScheduler`). When the `async` method resumes, it resumes executing in that context.

Dennis pointed out the TPL way of scheduling a task to the current `SynchronizationContext`, but in `async`/`await` world, that approach isn't necessary. Rather, you can explicitly schedule tasks to the thread pool via `Task.Run`:

```
async Task MyMethodAsync()
{
  // Whee, on a SynchronizationContext here!
  await Task.Run(() => { }); // Ooo, on the thread pool!
  // Back on the SynchronizationContext ...
  //  ... automagically!
}
```

I wrote my `SynchronizationContext` article precisely because the MSDN docs were so lacking. I have a [little more information on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2011/02/synchronizationcontext-odds-and-ends.html), but all the important bits are in the MSDN article. Many types use `AsyncOperation` rather than `SynchronizationContext` directly; the best documentation for this is [buried under the EAP docs (section "Threading and Context")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228974.aspx). But I should also point out that EAP is effectively obsolete due to `async`/`await`, so I wouldn't write code using `AsyncOperation` (or `SynchronizationContext`) - unless I was actually *writing my own* `SynchronizationContext`.

Comment: _SynchronizationContext (unless it is null, in which case it will capture the current TaskScheduler)._ Interesting... Actually, when reading up on TaskScheduler's, I start to think that a TaskScheduler - not an SynchronizationContext - is what I need for my original problem (not described here). Do you have good references of TaskSchedulers vs. SynchronizationContexts and what the difference actually is? (From looking at MSDN, both seem to be responsible for sheduling tasks onto threads, right?)

Comment: `SynchronizationContext` was developed with .NET 2.0 and is used to schedule delegates (synchronously or asynchronously). `TaskScheduler` was introduced in .NET 4.0 and is used to schedule tasks (asynchronously).