# Translating async-await C# code to F# with respect to the scheduler

Tags: c#, f#, task-parallel-library, c#-to-f#, orleans

I wonder if this is too a broad question, but recently I made myself to come across a piece of code I'd like to be certain on how to translate from C# into proper F#. The journey starts from [here (1)](https://orleans.codeplex.com/discussions/551757) (the original problem with TPL-F# interaction), and continues [here (2)](https://orleans.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/samples/GPSTracker/GPSTracker.GrainImplementation/PushNotifierGrain.cs) (some example code I'm contemplating to translate into F#).

The example code is too long to reproduce here, but the interesting functions are `ActivateAsync`, `RefreshHubs` and `AddHub`. Particularly the interesting points are

1. `AddHub` has a signature of `private async Task AddHub(string address)`.
2. `RefreshHubs` calls `AddHub` in a loop and collects a list of `tasks`, which it then awaits in the very end by `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)` and consequently the return value matches its signature of `private async Task RefreshHubs(object _)`.
3. `RefreshHubs` is called by `ActivateAsync` just as `await RefreshHubs(null)` and then in the end there's a call `await base.ActivateAsync()` matching the function signature `public override async Task ActivateAsync()`.

**Question:**

What would be the correct translation of such function signatures to F# that still maintains the interface and functionality and respects the default, custom scheduler? And I'm not otherwise too sure of this "async/await in F#" either. As in how to do it "mechanically". :)

The reason is that in the link "here (1)" there seem to be problem (I haven't verified this) in that F# async operations do not respect a custom, cooperative scheduler set by the (Orleans) runtime. Also, it's stated [here](https://orleans.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Interaction%20with%20Libraries%20and%20Services) that TPL operations escape the scheduler and go to the task pool and their use is therefore prohibited.

One way I can think of dealing with this is with a F# function as follows

```
//Sorry for the inconvenience of shorterned code, for context see the link "here (1)"...
override this.ActivateAsync() =
    this.RegisterTimer(new Func<obj, Task>(this.FlushQueue), null, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100.0), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100.0)) |> ignore

    if RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable then
        this.RefreshHubs(null) |> Async.awaitPlainTask |> Async.RunSynchronously
    else
        this.AddHub("http://localhost:48777/") |> Async.awaitPlainTask |> Async.RunSynchronously

    //Return value comes from here.
    base.ActivateAsync()

member private this.RefreshHubs(_) =
    //Code omitted, in case mor context is needed, take a look at the link "here (2)", sorry for the inconvinience...
    //The return value is Task.
    //In the C# version the AddHub provided tasks are collected and then the
    //on the last line there is return await Task.WhenAll(newHubAdditionTasks) 
    newHubs |> Array.map(fun i -> this.AddHub(i)) |> Task.WhenAll

member private this.AddHub(address) =
    //Code omitted, in case mor context is needed, take a look at the link "here (2)", sorry for the inconvinience...
    //In the C# version:
    //...
    //hubs.Add(address, new Tuple<HubConnection, IHubProxy>(hubConnection, hub))
    //} 
    //so this is "void" and could perhaps be Async<void> in F#... 
    //The return value is Task.
    hubConnection.Start() |> Async.awaitTaskVoid |> Async.RunSynchronously
    TaskDone.Done
```

The `startAsPlainTask` function is by **Sacha Barber** from [here](http://sachabarbs.wordpress.com/2014/05/15/f-28-integrating-with-task-parallel-library/). Another interesting option could be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022909/how-to-async-awaittask-on-plain-task-not-taskt) as

```
module Async =
    let AwaitTaskVoid : (Task -> Async<unit>) =
        Async.AwaitIAsyncResult >> Async.Ignore
```

**<edit:** I just noticed the `Task.WhenAll` would need to be awaited too. But what would be the proper way? Uh, time to sleep (a bad pun)...

**<edit 2:** At [here (1)](https://orleans.codeplex.com/discussions/551757) (the original problem with TPL-F# interaction) in Codeplex it was mentioned that F# uses synchronization contexts to push work to threads, whereas TPL does not. Now, this is a plausible explanation, I feel (although I'd still have problems in translating these snippets properly regardless of the custom scheduler). Some interesting additional information could be to had from

- [How to get a Task that uses SynchronizationContext? And how are SynchronizationContext used anyway?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16916253/how-to-get-a-task-that-uses-synchronizationcontext-and-how-are-synchronizationc)
- [Await, SynchronizationContext, and Console Apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/01/20/10259049.aspx) wherein an example `SingleThreadSynchronizationContext` is provided that looks like queues the work to be executed. Maybe this ought to be used?

I think I need to mention [Hopac](https://github.com/VesaKarvonen/Hopac) in this context, as an interesting tangential and also mention I'm out of reach for the next 50 odd hours or so in case all my cross-postings go out of hand.

**<edit 3**: [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/162396/daniel) and [svick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41071/svick) give good advice in the comments to use a custom task builder. Daniel provides a link to a one that's already defined in [FSharpx](https://github.com/fsprojects/fsharpx/blob/master/src/FSharpx.Core/ComputationExpressions/Monad.fs#L994).

Looking at the the source I see the interface with the parameters are defined as

```
type TaskBuilder(?continuationOptions, ?scheduler, ?cancellationToken) =
    let contOptions = defaultArg continuationOptions TaskContinuationOptions.None
    let scheduler = defaultArg scheduler TaskScheduler.Default
    let cancellationToken = defaultArg cancellationToken CancellationToken.None
```

If one were to use this in Orleans, it looks like the `TaskScheduler` ought to be `TaskScheduler.Current` as per documentation [here](https://orleans.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Interaction%20with%20Libraries%20and%20Services)

> Orleans has it's own task scheduler which provides the single threaded
>   execution model used within grains. It's important that when running
>   tasks the Orleans scheduler is used, and not the .NET thread pool.
>
> Should your grain code require a subtask to be created, you should use
>   Task.Factory.StartNew:
>
> await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>{ /* logic */ });
>
> This technique will use the current task scheduler, which will be the
>   Orleans scheduler.
>
> You should avoid using Task.Run, which always uses the .NET thread
>   pool, and therefore will not run in the single-threaded execution
>   model.

It looks there's a subtle difference between [TaskScheduler.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.current%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [TaskScheduler.Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.default%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Maybe this warrants a question on in which example cases there'll be an undesired difference. As the Orleans documentation points out not to use `Task.Run` and instead guides to `Task.Factory.StartNew`, I wonder if one ought to define [TaskCreationOptions.DenyAttachChild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as is recommended by such authorities as **Stephen Toub** at [Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx) and **Stephen Cleary** at [StartNew is Dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html). Hmm, it looks like the `.Default` will be `.DenyAttachChilld` unless I'm mistaken.

Moreover, as there is a problem with `Task.Run` viz `Task.Factory.CreateNew` regarding the custom scheduler, I wonder if this particular problem could be removed by using a custom [TaskFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as explained in [Task Scheduler (Task.Factory) and controlling the number of threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15428604/how-to-run-a-task-on-a-custom-taskscheduler-using-await) and [How to: Create a Task Scheduler That Limits Concurrency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee789351%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Hmm, this is becoming quite a long "pondering" already. I wonder how should I close this? Maybe if **svick** and **Daniel** could make their comments as answers and I'd upvote both and accept **svick's**?

Comment: I haven't used Orleans, but if it requires running all async code on a custom task scheduler coding it in F# is going to be a headache since `async` doesn't support that. The best you can do (AFAIK) is convert every `Task` to `Async<'T>` with something like `Async.AwaitTask` (yuck).

Comment: Indeed, that is what I was trying to do and just avoid async workflows. Alas, I'm not sure if I succeeded and anyhow I'm a bit shaky on how to translate certain C# patterns into F# (e.g. should I use ``async {}`` and if so how, or then again if not). Usually I write in either language and I haven't had the need to really think about it.

Comment: I don't know F# enough to comment on that part, but just wanted to point out what I believe are some bugs in the original C# code from your "here (2)" sample. `Flush` needs to be an `async Task` method rather than `void` because both `HubConnection.Start` and `IHupProxy.Invoke` are async methods returning `Task` that should be awaited. You probably want to collect Tasks as you go through the foreach loop and do Task.WhenAll at end of Flush method.

Comment: I would consider writing a custom [computation expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233182.aspx) builder (the one for `async` is [`AsyncBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340369.aspx)) that works directly with `Task` instead of `Async` and runs continuations using the current `TaskScheduler`.

Comment: @svick: That's a good suggestion, and [such a type is already available in FSharpx](https://github.com/fsprojects/fsharpx/blob/master/src/FSharpx.Core/ComputationExpressions/Monad.fs#L994).

Comment: @svick, so it looks like one doesn't have to build one as there is one already in FSharpx as pointed out by **Daniel**. Now, looking at the FSharpx code I see it uses ``TaskScheduler.Default`` as the default one and wonder if in this Orleans case one should supply [TaskScheduler.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.current%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead and if ``TaskContinuationOptions`` ought to be [TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use use `TaskBuilder` in FSharpx and pass in `TaskScheduler.Current`. Here's my attempt at translating `RefreshHubs`. Note that `Task<unit>` is used in lieu of `Task`.

```
let RefreshHubs _ =
    let task = TaskBuilder(scheduler = TaskScheduler.Current)
    task {
        let addresses = 
            RoleEnvironment.Roles.["GPSTracker.Web"].Instances
            |> Seq.map (fun instance ->
                let endpoint = instance.InstanceEndpoints.["InternalSignalR"]
                sprintf "http://%O" endpoint.IPEndpoint
            )
            |> Seq.toList

        let newHubs = addresses |> List.filter (not << hubs.ContainsKey)
        let deadHubs = hubs.Keys |> Seq.filter (fun x -> 
            not (List.exists ((=) x) addresses))

        // remove dead hubs
        deadHubs |> Seq.iter (hubs.Remove >> ignore)

        // add new hubs
        let! _ = Task.WhenAll [| for hub in newHubs -> AddHub hub |]
        return ()
    }
```

Comment: That's a good attempt. :) I think I get the gist of it (and the C# code was a bit "oh no" with all the "void FunctionMutatesInternalState()" stuff. Even in C# and classes it feels easier to pass in parameters and collect return values and assign them somewhere. Oh well, this was a good run. Thanks!