# How to use FSharpx TaskBuilder with functions taking parameters

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#, orleans

I have been lately programming with the [FSharpx library](https://fsprojects.github.io/fsharpx/) and especially its [TaskBuilder](https://github.com/fsprojects/fsharpx/blob/master/src/FSharpx.Core/ComputationExpressions/Monad.fs#L905). Now I wonder if it should be possible to define a function which takes parameters and takes a result. Such as

```
 let doTask(parameter:int) =
     let task = TaskBuilder(scheduler = TaskScheduler.Current)        
     task {
         return! Task.Factory.StartNew(fun() -> parameter + 1)
     } 

 match FSharpx.Task.run doTask(1) with
 | _ -> ()
```

Looking at the source code I see [run](https://github.com/fsprojects/fsharpx/blob/master/src/FSharpx.Core/ComputationExpressions/Monad.fs#L918) expects a function taking no parameters and returning a `Task<'a>`. There doesn't look like being examples on [FSharpx TaskTests](https://github.com/fsprojects/fsharpx/blob/master/tests/FSharpx.Tests/TaskTests.fs) either.

I'd appreciate if someone could advice how should I get a scenario like this going with FSharpx or if one isn't supposed to use the library like this for a reason I haven't quite grasped as of yet.

**<edit:** I believe I could wrap doTask as follows

```
 wrapperDoTask() = doTask(101)
 match FSharpx.Task.run wrapperDoTask with
 | _ -> ()
```

And it might work. I'm not with a compiler currently, so this is a bit of a handwaving. Does anyone have an opinion on any direction or did I just answer my own question? :)

**<edit2:**
I think I need to edit this one more time based on [MisterMetaphor's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/498176/mistermetaphor) answer. Especially his `P.S.`, I think, was well informing. I use FSharpx TaskBuilder to interop with C#, in which, as noted, tasks are returned as *hot* (with some minor exceptions), already running. This is in connection with my recent question [Translating async-await C# code to F# with respect to the scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24813359/translating-async-await-c-sharp-code-to-f-with-respect-to-the-scheduler) and in relation [Orleans](https://orleans.codeplex.com/) (I'll add some tags to beef up the context, maybe someone else is pondering these too).

When thinking in C# terms, what I try to achieve is to *await* the task result before returning, but without blocking. The behaviour I'm after is especially of that of `await` not `.Result`. The difference can be read, for instance, from

- [Await, and UI, and deadlocks! Oh my!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/await-and-ui-and-deadlocks-oh-my.aspx)
- [Don't Block on Async Code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Trying to think which context or scheduler or behavior or something is going on in terms of C# is somewhat fuzzy for me. Unfortunatelly it looks like I can't ignore all the details when it comes to interop. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Task.run` only if you want to wait for the task completion synchronously on the current thread. It takes a single parameter and you can consider that parameter a *task factory* -- i.e. a means to create a `Task<_>`. Unlike `Async<_>`, the `Task<_>` starts running as soon as it is created. That is not always a desirable behavior.

You could achieve similar results (a blocking wait for task completion) with `(doTask 101).Result`, but I think `Task.run` is more idiomatic to F#, in a way that it uses a `Result` return type to signal an error instead of raising an exception. It might be arguable which is better, depending on situation, but in my experience in simpler cases a special result type is more composable than exceptions.

Another point here is that you should avoid blocking waits (`Task.run`, `.Wait()`, `.Result`) as much as you can. (Ideally, you'd have one of those only at the top level of your program.)

P.S. This if out of scope of the question, but your `doTask` function looks funny. `task { return! Task.Factory.StartNew( ... ) }` is equivalent to `Task.Factory.StartNew( ... )`. What you probably wanted to do is `task { return parameter + 1 }`.

EDIT

So, in response to OP's question edit :) If you need the `await` behavior from C#, you just need to use `let! ...`. Like this:

```
task {
    let! x = someTask 1 2 3
    return x + 5
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I should elabore this on my question, but I'm using this library to interop with C# libraries and I suspect other new to F# have similar issues. Your *P.S.* gave me some *a-has* already! When it comes to threading, I'm "well familiar" with async-await (not an expert, the details seem to be aplenty always) and with regard to F# I've usually used the Async "as supposed to". This question stems from the C# land wherein some function returns a hot Task/Task<'a>, as you noted. I use ``TaskBuilder`` for interop and to collet results. Indeed, before returning, I'd like todo an "await"

Comment: If you don't need sophisticated `TaskFactory` configuration, to interop with C# you probably can get away with just `Async.AwaitTask` and `Async.StartAsTask`. If that's the case, you can use plain `async` in your F# code.

Comment: P.S. OK I've just noticed your [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24813359/translating-async-await-c-sharp-code-to-f-with-respect-to-the-scheduler) question and I think you should stick with the FSharpx TaskBuilder :)

Comment: Heh, indeed. I just edited my question. Maybe I've should done it the other way around. :) In any event, it's this *await* that's giving me some headache as that's the behavior I'd like to have and finding "mechanical patterns" so that I wouldn't need to mull this much of the details in my head.

By the way, I need to think if there's something more to this story. If I don't come up with anything (or someone else), I'll accept this one. This "P.S." was a good one, thanks for taking the time to think and write it.

Comment: Glad I could help. I've edited the answer and added response about `await`.