# Was ManuallyPumpedSynchronizationContext required in Jon Skeet's "TimeMachine" async unit test framework?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, async-await

I've just seen a video-class by Jon Skeet, where he talks about unit testing asynchronous methods. It was on a paid website, but I've found something similar to what he says, in his [book](http://apprize.info/c/depth/15.html) (just Ctrl+F "15.6.3. Unit testing asynchronous code").

The complete code can be found on [his github](https://github.com/jskeet/DemoCode/tree/master/AsyncIntro/Code/Testing.NUnit), but I have simplified it for the sake of my question (my code is basically `StockBrokerTest.CalculateNetWorthAsync_AuthenticationFailure_ThrowsDelayed()` but with TimeMachine and Advancer operations inlined).

Let's suppose we have a class to test a failed login (no unit test framework to simplify the question):

```csharp
public static class LoginTest
{
    private static TaskCompletionSource<Guid?> loginPromise = new TaskCompletionSource<Guid?>();

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("== START ==");

        // Set up
        var context = new ManuallyPumpedSynchronizationContext(); // Comment this
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(context); // Comment this

        // Run method under test
        var result = MethodToBeTested();
        Debug.Assert(!result.IsCompleted, "Result should not have been completed yet.");

        // Advancing time
        Console.WriteLine("Before advance");
        loginPromise.SetResult(null);
        context.PumpAll(); // Comment this
        Console.WriteLine("After advance");

        // Check result
        Debug.Assert(result.IsFaulted, "Result should have been faulted.");
        Debug.Assert(result.Exception.InnerException.GetType() == typeof(ArgumentException), $"The exception should have been of type {nameof(ArgumentException)}.");

        Console.WriteLine("== END ==");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static async Task<int> MethodToBeTested()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Before login");
        var userId = await Login();
        Console.WriteLine("After login");
        if (userId == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Bad username or password");
        }

        return userId.GetHashCode();
    }

    private static Task<Guid?> Login()
    {
        return loginPromise.Task;
    }
}
```

Where the implementation of `ManuallyPumpedSynchronizationContext` is:

```csharp
public sealed class ManuallyPumpedSynchronizationContext : SynchronizationContext
{
    private readonly BlockingCollection<Tuple<SendOrPostCallback, object>> callbacks;

    public ManuallyPumpedSynchronizationContext()
    {
        callbacks = new BlockingCollection<Tuple<SendOrPostCallback, object>>();
    }

    public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback callback, object state)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Post()");
        callbacks.Add(Tuple.Create(callback, state));
    }

    public override void Send(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Synchronous operations not supported on ManuallyPumpedSynchronizationContext");
    }

    public void PumpAll()
    {
        Tuple<SendOrPostCallback, object> callback;
        while(callbacks.TryTake(out callback))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("PumpAll()");
            callback.Item1(callback.Item2);
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
== START ==
Before login
Before advance
After login
After advance
== END ==
```

**My question is:** Why do we need the `ManuallyPumpedSynchronizationContext`?

Why isn't the default SynchronizationContext enough? The `Post()` method isn't even called (based on the output). I've tried commenting the lines marked with `// Comment this`, and the output is the same and the asserts pass.

If I understood correctly what Jon Skeet says in the video, the `SynchronizationContext.Post()` method should be called when we meet an `await` with a not-yet-completed task. But this is not the case. What am I missing?

**Aditional info**

Through my researches, I stumbled across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16916466/2420998). To try it, I changed the implementation of the `Login()` method to:

```csharp
private static Task<Guid?> Login()
{
    // return loginPromise.Task;
    return Task<Guid?>.Factory.StartNew(
        () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Login()");
            return null;
        },
        CancellationToken.None,
        TaskCreationOptions.None,
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

With that modification, the `Post()` method was indeed called. Output:

```
== START ==
Before login
Post()
Before advance
PumpAll()
Login()
After login
After advance
== END ==
```

So with Jon Skeet's use of `TaskCompletionSource`, was his creation of `ManuallyPumpedSynchronizationContext` not required?

*Note*: I think the video I saw was made just around C# 5 release date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, the `SetResult` is executing its continuation synchronously (directly). This is due to a couple of undocumented details:

1. `await` will schedule its continuations with the `TaskContinuationOption.ExecuteSynchronously` flag. [When I first discovered this behavior](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/dont-block-in-asynchronous-code.html), I [reported it as a bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/769322/waiting-on-task-can-deadlock-in-free-threaded-context). While I still think it's less surprising to have asynchronous continuations, there is a valid efficiency argument in favor of synchronous execution.
2. When `await` captures a `SynchronizationContext`, it will allow synchronous continuations if the current `SynchronizationContext` is the same instance as the captured `SynchronizationContext` (reference equality). Again, this is for performance reasons; equality on SyncCtx instances is not well-defined, but this works well enough in the real world.

So, you're seeing this behavior because at the `SetResult` line, `SynchronizationContext.Current` is set to the same SyncCtx that was captured by the `await` in `MethodToBeTested`.

A more realistic example would clear the current SyncCtx after calling the system under test. Thus the unit test code doesn't exist "inside" the SyncCtx; it only provides a SyncCtx for the system under test:

```
...
// Set up
var context = new ManuallyPumpedSynchronizationContext(); // Comment this
SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(context); // Comment this

// Run method under test
var result = MethodToBeTested();
Debug.Assert(!result.IsCompleted, "Result should not have been completed yet.");

// Tear down SyncCtx.
SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(null);

// Advancing time
...
```

Alternatively, you can pass `TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously` to the `TaskCompletionSource<T>` constructor. However, note [this bug](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3118695/runcontinuationsasynchronously-does-not-run-continuations-asynchronously) currently present in the .NET Framework will prevent this from working on full-desktop console apps; it only works for .NET Core console apps.

Or, of course, you can just wrap the `SetResult` in a `Task.Run`:

```
Task.Run(() => loginPromise.SetResult(null)).Wait();
```

which forces the continuation on a thread pool thread (without a SyncCtx), so the continuation will *have* to call `Post`.

As a final note, you may want to use my `AsyncContext` type from the AsyncEx library; it is a more fleshed-out custom `SynchronizationContext` that ties itself to a specific thread. I originally wrote `AsyncContext` for use with unit tests. When the SUT has asynchronous code, it commonly needs a SyncCtx. So much so, in fact, that xUnit *provides its own* built right into the test framework.

Comment: It seems similar to my answer, or I have missed some important details?

Comment: The behavior is due to the combination of the two details.

Comment: You are right. Note that passing `TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously` to `TaskCompletionSource<T>` seems to be working fine in this case even on full-desktop console apps (I tested on .NET 4.6 at least). Bug description states that it does not work only in certain conditions, and it seems conditions in this concrete code example are not those at which it bugs.

Comment: @Evk: Weird. It did not work when I tested it. [I'm running .NET Framework 4.6.2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx#net_b). Hope this is not a new bug in 4.6.2...

Comment: To be sure I created fresh console app (not core) in VS 2017, targeting .NET 4.6.2, copied code from OP post verbatim, added `TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously` and it works (by "works" I mean `Post` is getting called. My framework version if look at registry as you mentioned is 394802 which corresponds to ".NET Framework 4.6.2 installed on Windows 10 Anniversary Update".

Comment: @Evk: Definitely crazy. I did the same steps on my laptop, and it did not work (for the same definition of "work")...

Comment: Actually, if I copy-paste code from "this bug" link you provided (RunContinuationsAsynchronously does not run continuations asynchronously) - it will work correctly (output two different thread ids always). So it seems this bug is somehow fixed in my version. Maybe some patch\hotfix?

Comment: @Evk: It was my stupid mistake. My test code had `TaskContinuationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously` instead of `TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously`!

Comment: Sometimes copy-paste wins over manually typing :) So that means this bug was silently fixed and is no longer present in last .NET 4.6.

Answer (score 2):

I won't discuss what is the intended goal of this code, since I did not read the book or whole code on github link that you posted. I will just work with the code you posted in current question.

I would argue that in the code you provided, `ManuallyPumpedSynchronizationContext` is not used (regardless of where you run it: in console app, unit test, UI application and so on). It's `Post` method will not be called, because there is no synchronization context switch. It's usually stated that continuation of `await` will be `Post`ed to captured synchronization context, and that is in general true, but if after awaited method completes you are still on the same synchronization context - there is no reason to post anything - you are on the same context and can just continue. This is what happens here. When you call:

```
loginPromise.SetResult(null);
```

Current context is still `ManuallyPumpedSynchronizationContext`.

However, if you change it like this:

```
SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(null);
loginPromise.SetResult(null);
```

Now when `Login()` completes you are not on captured context any more, so continuation will indeed be `Post`ed to it, and so continuation will be delayed until you call `PumpAll`.

UPDATE: see @StephenCleary for a more complete explanation of this behavior (there is one more factor involved that is not mentioned in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

Because you executing your code in console application.
Console application doesn't have synchronization context `SynchronizationContext.Current` will be always null.

Purpose of `ManuallyPumpedSynchronizationContext` is "save" synchronization context where test method is executed and "pump" the result provided by of completed task to the saved context.

In console application saved context is `null` so you didn't see any difference

Comment: With provided code it will not make any difference if you will run it in UI application. `Post` will still not be called and the whole context will not be used.